# Perform foreach on values returned inside array

Tags: php, foreach

I'm not sure if I have worded this question correctly, but basically I have the following array result from WordPress I am trying to deal with:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; WP_User Object
        (
            [data] =&gt; stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] =&gt; 3
                    [user_login] =&gt; Jean Gomes
                    [user_pass] =&gt; $P$BvW6LK9/blGKLuSj.9spNPW3.v104..
                    [user_nicename] =&gt; jean-gomes
                    [user_email] =&gt; jean.gomes@dpa.dev
                    [user_url] =&gt; 
                    [user_registered] =&gt; 2014-08-28 10:56:39
                    [user_activation_key] =&gt; 
                    [user_status] =&gt; 0
                    [display_name] =&gt; Jean Gomes
                )

            [ID] =&gt; 3
            [caps] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [author] =&gt; 1
                )

            [cap_key] =&gt; dpa2335327_capabilities
            [roles] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; author
                )

            [allcaps] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [upload_files] =&gt; 1
                    [edit_posts] =&gt; 1
                    [edit_published_posts] =&gt; 1
                    [publish_posts] =&gt; 1
                    [read] =&gt; 1
                    [level_2] =&gt; 1
                    [level_1] =&gt; 1
                    [level_0] =&gt; 1
                    [delete_posts] =&gt; 1
                    [delete_published_posts] =&gt; 1
                    [wpseo_bulk_edit] =&gt; 1
                    [author] =&gt; 1
                )

            [filter] =&gt; 
        )

    [1] =&gt; WP_User Object
        (
            [data] =&gt; stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] =&gt; 4
                    [user_login] =&gt; Tammy Day
                    [user_pass] =&gt; $P$BejydpFxKDp60WruV71u0/JnJm9o.E.
                    [user_nicename] =&gt; tammy-day
                    [user_email] =&gt; tammy.day@dpa.dev
                    [user_url] =&gt; 
                    [user_registered] =&gt; 2014-08-28 10:57:23
                    [user_activation_key] =&gt; 
                    [user_status] =&gt; 0
                    [display_name] =&gt; Tammy Day
                )

            [ID] =&gt; 4
            [caps] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [author] =&gt; 1
                )
```

etc

I would like to perform a `foreach` using these results, for the ID.

E.g.

```
foreach ( $authors as $author_id ) {
```

But I don't know how to access the ID. I tried:

```
foreach ( $authors->ID as $author_id ) {
```

But obviously this can't work, as there is a number before that, is there an equivalent of:

```
foreach ( $authors['X']->ID as $author_id ) {
```

that I could use?

Sorry I know this is probably a silly question, but I'm quite stuck. I know I probably have to do a foreach within a foreach but I can't work out the syntax at all.

Comment: This should work: `foreach ($authors as $author) { echo $author->ID; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> foreach (array_expression as $value)
> ```
>
> On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

Read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation page for more details about `foreach` loop:

In your situation $value will pointer to the instance of `WP_User Object`. To access to the user's id just read object's property `ID`

```
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
    $author_id = $author->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant try this instead of foreach :

```
$i=0;
while ($i<count($authors)){
$author_id = $authors[$i]['data']['id'];
//Do whatever you want here.
$i=$i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the dump states, the array elements are instances of WP_User. You can use the following loop to fetch the IDs:

```
foreach ($authors as $User) {
    $author_id = $User->ID;
    // Act
}
```

For a reference of the WP_User class, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User